# How can i take the remain of a modulo in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a simple explanation of a public and private key algorithm. The encryption part is working fine, however the decryption part is a bit off. I only want the 29 that's a remain of modulo(2^7,33). this is what I have so far:

```
p= 3
q= 11
n = p*q
z = (p-1)*(q-1)
e = 7
d = (z + 1)/e
a= divmod(d*e,z)

PublicKey = (e,n)
PrivateKey = (d,n)

#Encrypt
message = 2
c = divmod(2**e,n)
print c

#Decrypt
decryption = divmod((c**2),n)
print decryption
```

The error is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Python27/rsa2.py", line 17, in <module>
    decryption = divmod((c**2),n)
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Comment: Well, `c` is a tuple, so I don't see how that's unexpected... instead of `c = divmod(2 ** e, n)`, just do `c = 2 ** e % n` or even better `c = pow(2, e, n)`, which uses the standard modexp algorithm which is faster than your code

Answer (score 0):

your problem is at the end , at this line:

```
decryption = divmod((c**2),n)
```

remove the () around c variable